# Show tooltip when the user selects item in QComboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I want to show the tooltip with the text and the time when user selects the item in list view (hovers the mouse on the item in the list view) of `QCombobox`.

I'm using a custom `QComboBox` with `QItemDelegate`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Are you looking for [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#setItemData)? For example:

```
 ui->comboBox->setItemData(0, "This is a tooltip for item[0]", Qt::ToolTipRole);
```

[image]

Comment: How would I achieve this in designer?

Answer (score 10):

Since I did not find an example, I'll post this here.

The way to do this on **Python** (PyQt5) is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
...
combobox.setItemData(0, "This is a tooltip for item[0]",QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole);
```